# how to create dynamaping in elasticsearch for dynamic fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to create the dynamic mapping for unknown new fields in the index using a dynamic template. My sample mapping is:

```
{  
   "indexname":{  
      "dynamic_templates":[  
         {  
            "template_1":{  
               "match":"*",
               "dynamic fields":{  
                  "type":"dynamictype",
                  "index":"not_analyzed"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I'm little bit confused to create the dynamic mapping is anyone kindly guide me to solve this.

i want to create the mapping multiple fields during the run time using java API is any one to guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this :

```
 {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "template_1": {
            "path_match": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

and I am not pretty sure about the 'dynamictype' in your code. You have to specify an exact type.

edit :

```
{
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "dynamic_1": {
        "path_match": "abcd*",
        "mapping": {
          "include_in_all": true,
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "dynamic_2": {
        "path_match": "address.phone.*",
        "mapping": {
          "include_in_all": true,
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The first one(named template_1) will be applied to all new fields starting with 'abcd' and second (named template_2) will be applied to all nested fields with in 'phone' which is already nested in 'address' field.

Comment: thanks for ur response i already tried this i want to create the mapping for multiple fields during i had no idea about it can u guid me to do that using java api

Comment: you should have a slight clue about the path of the fields for specifying different mappings for multiple fields. Otherwise you can use a wild card and specify a single template as in the first example. see my edits.

Comment: thanks for your response after i using the example you mentioned above i faced the Root type mapping not empty after parsing! error it is not worked expectedly can you guide me to fix it.